# How to handle column separator being present in one of the columns without using any in-built library in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I want to read a CSV file in Python3 but cannot use any library due to some constraints. In almost every row, one or more columns contain the commas (",") and using `row.split(',')` is causing issues as the number of columns to get increased.

My code is:

```
import csv

file_name = "train_1.csv"
columns = [
    "PassengerId",
    "Survived",
    "Pclass",
    "Name",
    "Sex",
    "Age",
    "SibSp",
    "Parch",
    "Ticket",
    "Fare",
    "Cabin",
    "Embarked"
]
print("Total columns should be: {}".format(len(columns)))
with open(file_name, 'r') as reader:
    for line in reader.readlines():
        row_data = line.split(',')
        if len(row_data) != len(columns):
            print('This row does not have the required # of columns: {}'.format(
                len(row_data)))
            print(row_data)
```

My output(wrong) is:

```
['1', '0', '3', '"Braund', ' Mr. Owen Harris"', 'male', '22', '1', '0', 'A/5 21171', '7.25', '', 'S\n']
```

Instead, it should be:

```
['1', '0', '3', '"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris"', 'male', '22', '1', '0', 'A/5 21171', '7.25', '', 'S']
```

The extra column was due to the name being split into two instead of one and the `\n` in the last column.

However, my main concern is extra columns getting split. Note: the problem is solved by CSV reader but due to library constraints, I cannot really use any library.

Partial input is:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
```

Complete data is available [here](https://pastebin.com/FxZPzP23).

Comment: Please show examples of the input.  If `csv.reader` can handle the problem, then it seems that there is some information in the input that you can parse to find those fields.  From what you put here, it looks as if you have those fields enclosed in quotation marks, which means that you can identify them in your input parsing.  Is the `ast.eval` family of any use to you, or is that another proscribed package.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I sense a pattern: the `name` column is quoted with `"` and it seems(highly anecdotal observation) that this column has commas in it. What say you?

Comment: And no, I cannot import any package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After observing the csv file, I found out that the name column is messed and should be handled.

```
file_name = "train_1.csv"
columns = [
    "PassengerId",
    "Survived",
    "Pclass",
    "Name",
    "Sex",
    "Age",
    "SibSp",
    "Parch",
    "Ticket",
    "Fare",
    "Cabin",
    "Embarked"
]
print("Total columns should be: {}".format(len(columns)))
header = False
with open(file_name, 'r') as reader:
    for line in reader.readlines():
        line = line[:-1]
        if not header:
            header = True
            continue
        line_pre_name = line.split('"', 1)[0].split(',')[:-1]
        name = [line.split('"', 2)[1]]
        line_post_name = line.split('"')[-1].split(',')[1:]
        row_data = line_pre_name + name + line_post_name
        if len(row_data) != len(columns):
            print('This row does not have the required # of columns: {}'.format(
                len(row_data)))
            print(row_data)
```

Comment: Using your given input, this is storing an empty string instead of the final value.

Answer (score 1):

The comma in Name column values breaks the name into 2 columns. Below solution fixes this, and also removes new line from Embarked column values

```
print("Total columns should be: {}".format(len(columns)))
with open(file_name, 'r') as reader:
    for line in reader.readlines():
        row_data = line.replace('\n', '').split(',')
        if len(row_data) != len(columns):
            row_data[3] = (row_data[3]+ ',' + row_data[4])
            del row_data[4]
            print(row_data)
        else:
            print(row_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to use any builtin modules is an odd restriction, but creating your own csv parser is easy enough.

As you noticed, you'll have to handle cases where the value contains a comma, which CSV handles by quoting the whole string.

In the full data link, there's also this row that adds another wrinkle:

```
889,0,3,"Johnston, Miss. Catherine Helen ""Carrie""",female,,1,2,W./C. 6607,23.45,,S
```

This is a value with an embedded comma, so it's quoted. However, it also has a quoted value *within* it, so the CSV format "escapes" those quotes by doubling them. I am assuming you need to preserve these escaped quotes.

```
def csv_values(text_line, delim=','):
    row = []
    embedded = False
    parts = []

    for word in text_line.split(delim):
        # Set flag marking start of quoted value
        if word.startswith('"'):
            embedded = True

        if embedded:
            # If scanning a quoted value (with embedded commas),
            # add the current portion to the accumulator
            # word = word.replace('""', r'"')
            parts.append(word)
        else:
            # Otherwise, append the value to the collection
            row.append(word)

        # Unset flag, marking end of quoted value
        if word.endswith('"'):
            embedded = False
            # Add the accumulated value
            # row.append(','.join(parts)[1:-1])
            row.append(','.join(parts))
            # Reset the accumulator
            parts = []

    return row
```

This implementation is my "as-is" approach, meaning that the only thing I'm doing is accumulating values that have an embedded comma. I get this result using rows 882-891:

```
['882', '0', '3', '"Markun, Mr. Johann"', 'male', '33', '0', '0', '349257', '7.8958', '', 'S']
['883', '0', '3', '"Dahlberg, Miss. Gerda Ulrika"', 'female', '22', '0', '0', '7552', '10.5167', '', 'S']
['884', '0', '2', '"Banfield, Mr. Frederick James"', 'male', '28', '0', '0', 'C.A./SOTON 34068', '10.5', '', 'S']
['885', '0', '3', '"Sutehall, Mr. Henry Jr"', 'male', '25', '0', '0', 'SOTON/OQ 392076', '7.05', '', 'S']
['886', '0', '3', '"Rice, Mrs. William (Margaret Norton)"', 'female', '39', '0', '5', '382652', '29.125', '', 'Q']
['887', '0', '2', '"Montvila, Rev. Juozas"', 'male', '27', '0', '0', '211536', '13', '', 'S']
['888', '1', '1', '"Graham, Miss. Margaret Edith"', 'female', '19', '0', '0', '112053', '30', 'B42', 'S']
['889', '0', '3', '"Johnston, Miss. Catherine Helen ""Carrie"""', 'female', '', '1', '2', 'W./C. 6607', '23.45', '', 'S']
['890', '1', '1', '"Behr, Mr. Karl Howell"', 'male', '26', '0', '0', '111369', '30', 'C148', 'C']
['891', '0', '3', '"Dooley, Mr. Patrick"', 'male', '32', '0', '0', '370376', '7.75', '', 'Q']
```

If you would prefer to not have the enclosing quote and to un-escape the embedded quotes, you can un-comment lines 14 & 24, and comment out line 25. That approach will then give this:

```
['882', '0', '3', 'Markun, Mr. Johann', 'male', '33', '0', '0', '349257', '7.8958', '', 'S']
['883', '0', '3', 'Dahlberg, Miss. Gerda Ulrika', 'female', '22', '0', '0', '7552', '10.5167', '', 'S']
['884', '0', '2', 'Banfield, Mr. Frederick James', 'male', '28', '0', '0', 'C.A./SOTON 34068', '10.5', '', 'S']
['885', '0', '3', 'Sutehall, Mr. Henry Jr', 'male', '25', '0', '0', 'SOTON/OQ 392076', '7.05', '', 'S']
['886', '0', '3', 'Rice, Mrs. William (Margaret Norton)', 'female', '39', '0', '5', '382652', '29.125', '', 'Q']
['887', '0', '2', 'Montvila, Rev. Juozas', 'male', '27', '0', '0', '211536', '13', '', 'S']
['888', '1', '1', 'Graham, Miss. Margaret Edith', 'female', '19', '0', '0', '112053', '30', 'B42', 'S']
['889', '0', '3', 'Johnston, Miss. Catherine Helen "Carrie"', 'female', '', '1', '2', 'W./C. 6607', '23.45', '', 'S']
['890', '1', '1', 'Behr, Mr. Karl Howell', 'male', '26', '0', '0', '111369', '30', 'C148', 'C']
['891', '0', '3', 'Dooley, Mr. Patrick', 'male', '32', '0', '0', '370376', '7.75', '', 'Q']
```

In any case, you can use the function like this:

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as in_file:
    csv_lines = in_file.splitlines()

# Separate header from rest
headers, lines = csv_lines[0], csv_lines[1:]

for line in lines:
    print(csv_values(line))
```